# My cloth is not clipping when I animate my character

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

Clipping is turned on for my trousers but when I move the leg, the trousers split from the bottom:
[image]

Comment: I think you need more detail to this question: a single (x-ray) pic is not enough to demonstrate what you mean.  Additionally, I'm not sure how you're using clipping here-- are you referring to the clipping option on the mirror modifier?  Has nothing to do with cloth.

Comment: Apologies for that. So I was just about to begin animating my character. When I moved the leg using the armature I noticed the trousers from the bottom become split (as you can see from the image). You can see his groins. Why are the trousers not staying clipped in the center? Why are they essntially "ripping"?

Comment: They must not be merging, so they must not be with 0.002 units of the origin's YZ plane.  Try applying  your mirror on a copy and check out what's happening at the midline.